# Вывод изображения во всплывающем окне

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Надумал я сделать изображения как у вк, при нажатие на изображения открывается окно, где само фото и автор, лайки и прочие.

Так сразу первое в голову приходит делать так: всю информацию об авторе, лайки и прочие хранить в бд.

Но тут же вопрос: как загружать данные во время открытия окна и определять `id` изображения, на которое пользователь нажал и по `id` загружать данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, Вконтакте именно так и работает. Открывается изображение - по его ID подтягиваются данные и отображаются.

Можете сделать предзагрузку. К примеру:
Открыли изображение - загрузили данные на него, следующее и предыдущее. В таком случае при переключении(назад/вперёд) возьмете данные с кеша и сразу отобразите - не стучась к серверу за ними.

Что бы определить ID - присвойте ему data аттрибут.

Пример:

```js
document.querySelector('div').onclick=openImage;

function openImage(e){
 var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
 loadImageData(id);
  openImageBox();
}

function loadImageData(id){
alert('Загружаем данные для изображения с ID: '+id)
}
function openImageBox(){
alert('Открываем большую картинку')

}
```

```css
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div data-id="1">

</div>
```

Для лучшего эффекта организуйте так пути:

/thumb/id - для маленькой картинки

/preview/id - для большой картинки

В таком случае вы сможете начать загружать большую картинку сразу же после клика, не дожидаясь данных с сервера

Answer (score 0):

Ид изображения обычно помещать в атрибуты тега img, например

```
<img src="..." data-id="123" - вот айдишник
```

Загрузка данных в модальное окно делается с помощью ajax - обычно используют jquery.